# Is eduroam blocking all requests toward clients?

Tags: firewall, lan

I have tested some features of the eduroam network, and it seems that many requests between client computers are blocked. Does it mean that I cannot share files within the network? And does it mean that my computer would not be affected by viruses or malwares like WannaCry?

To be specifit with the blocking, for example, I have two computers connected to eduroam, with IP address `123.45.67.8` and `123.45.67.9`. When `123.45.67.8` sends an UDP datagram to `123.45.67.9`, the receiver cannot receive the datagram.

Comment: Sadly, questions about networks you don't control are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Eduroam defines a minimum number of services that participating universities must allow as part of the eduroam partnership. Beyond those minimum requirements though universities may not allow anything additional. The eduroam are often considered "guest networks" and likely will not have access to other wireless networks in a given university. You did not state what port/protocol you were sending on, but if it is listed outside of those minimums you will likely need to use a VPN connection to form a connection. If you have further questions I would advise contacting the helpdesk of said participating university.

HTTP/HTTPS [tcp/80, tcp/443]
SSH [tcp/22]
Email:
IMAP(2+4,3,S) [tcp/143, tcp/220, tcp/993]
POP(3S) [tcp/110, tcp/995]
SMTP(S/STARTTLS) [tcp/465, tcp/587]
VPN
Standard IPSec VPN [IP proto 50 (ESP), IP proto 51 (AH), udp/500 (IKE)]
OpenVPN 2.0 [udp/1194]
Cisco IPSec VPN over TCP [tcp/10000]
PPTP VPN [IP proto 47 (GRE) and tcp/1723]
Miscellaneous
IPv6 Tunnel Broker Service [IP proto 41]
IPSec NAT-Traversal [udp/4500]
Passive (S)FTP [tcp/21]
RDP [tcp/3389]

For more information on the minimum requirements for traffic on eduroam networks please see: https://www.eduroam.us/node/96

Additional comment: When connecting to public networks such as eduroam, you should ensure that your network connection is set to "public" which should block all external requests unless you added an exception. Do not assume you are safe on any network.